# How can i connect my wallet to metamask without a server?

Tags: metamask

i need to connect my wallet to metamask, just i am using html + js (i have not to use any server neither other framework), then i implemented like this:

```
const connect = async () => {
  if (window.ethereum) { //check if Metamask is installed
    try {
    const address = await window.ethereum.enable(); //connect Metamask
```

but here `if (window.ethereum) {` i am getting always `undefined`

can i get up metamak

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Metamask's now archived [FAQ](https://github.com/MetaMask/faq/blob/9257d7d52784afa957c12166aff20682cf692ae5/DEVELOPERS.md#:%7E:text=due%20to%20browser%20security%20restrictions%2C%20we%20can%27t%20communicate%20with%20dapps%20running%20on%20file%3A%2F%2F.%20please%20use%20a%20local%20server%20for%20development.).

> Due to browser security restrictions, we can't communicate with dapps
> running on file://. Please use a local server for development.

***"window.ethereum"*** is injected by MetaMask to a host, HTML opened on your browser is basically like a "text" file rendered by the browser, which won't trigger any browser extension's injection.

You don't need an actual server to test things out though, you can do it through localhost-ing.

The easiest one is through Visual Studio Code's extension - Live server.

Or if you're familiar with node.js.

```
cd <your-folder>
```

then from there:

```
npx http-server
```

Comment: there is not a way to worki without a server?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. it's due to browser security restrictions. Updated answer to reflect their archived FAQ.